# clang-format add {} around statement after if() while() for()

Tags: clang-format

I'd like to know if clang-format could be setup to reduce non-`compound_statement` into `{ non-compound_statement; }` in `iteration_statement`.

```
statement
: labeled_statement
| compound_statement
| expression_statement
| selection_statement
| iteration_statement
| jump_statement
;
iteration_statement
: WHILE '(' expression ')' statement
| DO statement WHILE '(' expression ')' ';'
| FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement ')' statement
| FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement expression ')' statement
;
```

**Example**

Input:

```
if (exp) foo = 1;
```

Output:

```
if (exp) { foo = 1; }
```

Then the beautifier would indent as needed.

Comment: clang-format might not be what you're looking for. Have you tried using `clang-tidy`?

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is outside of the scope of what clang-format tries to achieve:

> - The only lexical elements clang-format should touch are: whitespaces,    string-literals and comments. Any other changes
>     ranging from ordering    includes to removing superfluous paranthesis
>     are not in the scope of    this tool.

Source: http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Design-clang-format-td3980439.html

However clang tidy can, the feature flag is called `readability-braces-around-statements`.

Source: http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-braces-around-statements.html